# Is $X$ a $T_1$ space? (i.e., given a pair of distinct points in $X$, does each one of them have a neighborhood not containing the other?)

Tags: general-topology

Define a topology $T$ on the closed interval $X = [−1, 1]$ by declaring a set to be open if it either does not contain the point $0$, or it does contain $(−1, 1)$.

1. Is $X$ a $T_1$ space? (i.e., given a pair of distinct points in $X$, does each one of them have a neighborhood not containing the other?)
2. Show that $X$ locally path-connected

Comment: Look at $0,1/2$. Every neighborhood of $0$ contains $1/2$. Therefore, it is not $T_1$

Comment: Can I say because (-1,1) on the real is Hausdorff, so it has to be a T1?

Comment: All points different from $0$ are open. Therefore every point $x\neq0$ has a neighborhood basis, namely just the neighborhood $\{x\}$, which is path connected ($x$ is connected to itself by the constant path). Now, the neighborhoods of $0$ are $[-1,1)$, $(-1,1)$ and $(-1,1]$. Therefore $(-1,1)$ is a neighborhood basis of $0$. Every point $x\in(-1,1)$ can be path connected to $0$ by the path $f(0)=0$ and $f(t)=x$ for $t\in(0,1]$. Observe that $f$ is continuous from $[0,1]$ to $[-1,1]$ with that topology.

Comment: For the separation properties $T_0,T_1,T_2$ we have $T_2\implies T_1\implies T_0 .$

Answer (score 1):

If a space is T1 it is equivalent to saying that singleton sets are closed. You need to only verify whether singletons are closed or not.